# What is the shorthand for mapping a specific value to something else?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

So what I want to do is map a specific value in a `Traversable` to something else. To illustrate,

```
scala> Seq("hello", "\\N", "world").map { s =>
     |   s match {
     |     case "\\N" => null
     |     case _ => s
     |   }
     | }
res1: Seq[String] = List(hello, null, world)
```

While this works, it takes a lot more lines than I would like it to. Is there a shorthand to achieve the same concisely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170862/replacing-every-occurrence-of-some-element-by-some-other-element

Comment: The duplicate question already uses the shorter form.

Comment: Why are you using `null`? Typically, in my experience of 2 years Scala professionally, there's a social contract that developers won't use `null` in a code-base, i.e. no need to check for NPE in Scala code.

Comment: Because I these `\N` to be interpreted as `null`s in a Spark DataFrame. I don't like `null`s either. But I don't think there is another option there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a `Map` of substitutions,

```
val m = Map("\\N" -> (null:String))
```

Thus get the replacing value from the `Map` or else the original value if not declared in the `Map`,

```
Seq("hello", "\\N", "world").map(v => m.getOrElse(v,v))
```

Comment: This sounds like a simple but elegant way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Seq("hello","\\N","world").map(s => if (s == "\\N") null else s)
```